# How to make a sorted array of objects have distinct values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say I have the following array of objects:

```
let teams = [
  { Name: "Los Angeles Lakers", Championships: "17" },
  { Name: "Boston Celtics", Championships: "17" },
  { Name: "Cleveland Cavaliers", Championships: "01" },
  { Name: "San Antonio Spurs", Championships: "05" },
];
```

I sort the array:

```
teams.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.Championships).localeCompare(parseInt(b.Championships)));
```

And so I have:

[image]

The thing is now I want to have distinct values for the property **Championships**, so the final result would be (I don't care which final result I will have, I just want to make it work):

[image]

Or the following:

[image]

How can I do it properly?

Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: what is unique value? btw, you sort by string and leading zero is a valid character. for sorting by number, you could sort with the delta of both values: `parseInt(a.Championships, 10) - parseInt(b.Championships, 10)`

Comment: I mean, the objects with Name property "Los Angeles Lakers" and "Boston Celtics" have the same value for Championship property. I want to filter just one of them as both have the same value for this property. So after the filter I would have and array of 3 objects and not 4

Comment: FYI the term you want is *"distinct"* rather than *"unique"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this.

A naïve approach would be just to iterate over the teams collection, search the results to see if you are already including a team with that specific championship count. If there is no team, add it. This can be slow because you will need to iterate over the results N times for N items but is probably good enough for normal use cases.

```
const distinctBy = (array, keySelector) => {
  return array.reduce((result, i) => {
    const index = result.findIndex((j) => keySelector(j) === keySelector(i));
    
    if (index === -1) {
      result.push(i);
    }
    
    return result;
  }, []);
};

distinctBy(teams, (team) => team.Championships);
```

The performance of this can be improved on my using a set to store known keys potentially reducing iteration count by an order of magnitude from the previous solution.

```
const distinctBy = (array, keySelector) => {
  const result = [];
  const keys = new Set();

  for (let item of array) {
    const key = keySelector(item);

    if (!keys.has(key)) {
      keys.add(key);
      result.push(item);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

distinctBy(teams, (team) => team.Championships);
```

If you already know your data set is sorted, you can simply iterate the collection and include values as long as the current key does not match the previous key. This common technique in databases and is very fast. Again it requires data to be sorted.

```
const distinctBy = (array, keySelector) => {
  const result = [];
  let previous = "";

  for (let item of array) {
    const key = keySelector(item);

    if (key != previous) {
      result.push(item);
    }

    previous = key;
  }

  return result;
};

distinctBy(teams, (team) => team.Championships);
```